# Youtube video search result sorting order does not match with youtube.com

Tags: youtube-data-api

Youtube data API v3:

Youtube data api v3 does not return video list in the same order as youtube.com when searching with a specific query like "old hindi songs"

Why??

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for this. But this doesn't mean that you're doing something wrong. It's supposed to be this way.

For example if you are logged in in youtube, youtube will order the results taking in account videos you watched or liked, while the data api does not have access to this info. Also it may filter the results based on your region, while the api will filter by region only if specifically told so.

Try running your browser in incognito, don't log in into youtube, and perform from there a youtube search. The results should 90% match those received from api v3 if of course your request to the api has the **order** parameter set to **relevance**.